# Find if the set E is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For $E= \Big\{ \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)}: n=1, 2,3, \ldots \Big\}\subset \mathbb{R}$

Find if $E$ is compact or not by showing $E^°,E'$ and $\bar{E}$. If it's not compact, prove it.

I know that the set is not open and and its points gets arbitrarily close to $0$.
I just don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What do you mean "by showing $E^°,E'$ and $\bar{E}$"? What exactly is $E'$ for you?

Comment: **Hint :** $E$ is not closed, since it has a sequence that converges to $0$, but does not contain $0$.

Comment: Oh sorry i meant  interior, accumulation points and adherence. E’ is accumulation points

Comment: What should you do with that? Determine their values?

Comment: I think its to determine if its compact or not, but im pretty sure its not compact since E is not closed. Beside that i dont really know how to prove it

Comment: For each $x\in E$ there exists $S(x)>0$ such that the interval $I(x)=(\,x-S(x),\,x+S(x)\,) $contains no point of $E$ except $x$. E.g. we may let $S((-1)^n/(2n+1))=2^{-1}(2n+1)^{-1}(2n+5)^{-1}.$ Then $C=\{I(x):x\in E\}$ is an infinite open cover of $E$ with no finite sub-cover; in fact $no$ proper subset of $C$ is a cover of $E.$

Comment: $0$ is a limit point of this set that is not in this set, so the set is not compact.

Comment: What is your topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3):

The set is bounded, because
$$
-1\le \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\le 1
$$
for every positive integer $n$.

Saying it's “unbounded at $0$” means nothing. What's true is that $0$ is a limit point of the set $E$ because it's easy to see that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=0
$$
On the other hand, $0\notin E$ and so $E$ is not closed, hence you also have information about compactness.

Are there other limit points? Are there inner points?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $0$ is an accumulation point of our set $E$ since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=0$. However, notice that $0 \not\in E$. Therefore, $E$ is not closed.

As another user has shown, $E$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$. This can be shown more rigorously by the following observation.

Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$. Then,  $|a_1|=\frac{1}{3}, |a_2| = \frac{1}{5}$ and from there you would show inductively that for each $a_n \in E, |a_{n+1}| < |a_n| < | \pm 1|$, which implies that $-1 < a_n < 1$

Regarding the interior of $E$, since we have a $(-1)^n$ in our limit expression, we have an alternating sequence. Then for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}<0 \, ,\hspace{0.8cm} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2(n+1)+1}>0$$

We can conclude that $$a_n<0<a_{n+1}$$

One thing you could deduce from this statement is that $d(a_n,a_n+1)= \varepsilon >0$ for all $a_n \in E$. Then there does not exist $\delta>0$ such that $(a_n-\delta,a_n+\delta) \subset E$. This means that each point $a_n \in E$ is isolated since there exists an open neighborhood of each point that is merely $a_n$'s singleton. That is to say, for each $a_n$, $\{a_n\} \subset E.$Since each $a_n$ has no open neighborhoods except its singleton, we conclude that int$(E)=\varnothing$.

If this were the discrete topology, $\{a_n\}$ would be open, but since I'm assuming this is natural topology on $\mathbb{R}$, we would find that $\{a_n\}^c=(-\infty, a_n) \cup (a_n, \infty)$ is a union of open sets which is open. This implies that $\{a_n\}$ is closed and therefore, $a_n \not\in $ int$(E)$ since int$(E)$ is the union of all open subsets of $E$.